# Is there a way to avoid the password prompt in pg_basebackup?

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to get a server provisioned using ansible, meaning that I can't type in a password. I'm doing a master-slave topology and I need to run `pg_basebackup` on the slave machine to accomplish this. I've looked into using `.pgpass`, but that appears to be for my shell user, not the `postgres` account.

Is this possible? Or will I have to make a manual stage in my deployment?

Comment: It's a connection like any other connection. This related answer may be useful: [*Run batch file with psql command without password*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15593100/939860)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `.pgpass` in the home directory for the `postgres` user, or whatever user you run `pg_basebackup` as.

Link to the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [ansible-vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) that way you won't leave an unencrypted copy of the password laying around on the filesystem of the target host.

`.pgpass` is fine for your dev environment, but it's about as effective as taping plain text passwords to the bottom of your keyboard in terms of effective security.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I'll definitely consider doing that at some point.

Comment: Is the vault a commercial product?  If yes, are you affiliated with the company (coworker, retailer, other)?  In any case, how do you set it up to do what the OP wants?  Furthermore, if you secure your OS, the `.pgpass` way is totally acceptable in production, too.

Comment: So how do you tell Postgres (or more specifically: libpq) to read this encrypted file?